# Redirect to a URL with 404 status code in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

How to redirect a http request to a specific URL with 404 status code. I am using

```
Response.sendRedirect("/404userfriendlypage")
```

The response code of requested URL is 301, instead i need that to be 404. and then redirect to this user friendly error page.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this  by using below code.

```
Response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```

which sends 404 to front end for the requested url. At application level, we have a configuration where if 404 code receives redirect to a user friendly page.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in your spring controller using this syntax

```
        return "redirect:/urlNotExist";
```

Above redirection will give 404 on to client as "/urlNotExist" route has no mapping.

Now you can either code on client-side at client side for redirecting to user friendly error page. Or Simply setup a @ControllerAdvice for server-side redirection to user friendly error page.

**Solution in plain java.**

Redirect using simple Response.sendRedirect("path");

```
Response.sendRedirect("/404Genratingpage")
```

And to redirect to a custom error page when staus is 404 or on some other criteria. You need to override Response.sendRedirect method.

```
 public class CustomResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

     @Override
    public void sendRedirect(String location) {

      //custom logic to redirect to a user friendly error page.
  super.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/404userfriendlypage.jsp");
    }

}
```

And for your 404 or any other status , try setting response status like below in your 404userfriendlypage.jsp.

```
<%response.setStatus(404);%>
```

Comment: Can you provide the solution in plain java. Application is not based on Spring.

Comment: Thank you @Sacin for your answer, It didn't solved my problem. I have to redirect with 404 error code as response. Using above code, it gives 301 but i need 404